# Dynamically hide form submit button if no text within textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, submit

So I am sure there is a simple way to do this using JQuery but I am not very familiar with JQuery, so I figured I would ask the experts :)

So I am building a large HTML string in my JS which gets inserted via .innerHtml() and I will spare you the whole string as its not all important for this question, but I am just wondering how to do a simple toggle that will only show my SUBMIT button if any of the textarea's have text within (there is one textarea per row)

So I have my form:

```
    tableBody = "<form id='ssdSchedDR' name='ssdSchedDR' onsubmit='return emailSSD();'>";
```

I continue to build out a table and output row by row, depending on how many rows my query deems should be built.

My last column is the textarea:

```
    tableBody += "<td><div id='divEmailMsg"+i+"'><textarea id='EmailMsg"+i+"' name='EmailMsg' class='clsEmailMsg' onchange='chgEmailMsg("+i+");' rows='2' cols='50'>"
   + "</textarea></div>"
   + "<input type='checkbox'  name='emailType' value='sched' id='sched'><span class='checkboxtext'>Sched&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>"
   + "<input type='checkbox'  name='emailType' value='implant' id='implant'><span class='checkboxtext'>Implant</span>"
   + "</td>";
```

So basically, I just want the SUBMIT button to show up if text is entered in any of the EmailMsg[i] places and also (as a bonus) if one of the checkboxes is selected for the said textarea.  Let me know if there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

several points, here :

- you should post here the code of what you tried, if not, you are taking the risk of a downvote on your OP
- you should not use `onchange` nor `onsubmit` in the HTML, but rather addEventListener() or jQuery#on in a separate js file (or at least `<script>` tag)
- innerHTML is NOT a function, so it cannot be invoked, don't confuse domElement.innerHTML (property with getter and setter) and jQueryElement.html() (function).

See jQuery API : [hide](http://ap%C3%AE.jquery.com/hide)  and [show](http://ap%C3%AE.jquery.com/show) and [on](http://ap%C3%AE.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
$(document).on("change","textarea.clsEmailMsg",function(){
  var matches = $("textarea.clsEmailMsg").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).val().length && $(this).closest("td").find(":checkbox:checked").length)
  });
  if(matches.length)
    $(":submit").show();
  else
   $(":submit").hide();
});
```

```js
$(document).on("change","textarea.clsEmailMsg, :checkbox",function(){
      var matches = $("textarea.clsEmailMsg").filter(function(){
        return ($(this).val().length && $(this).closest("td").find(":checkbox:checked").length)
      });
      if(matches.length)
        $(":submit").show();
      else
       $(":submit").hide();
    });
```

```css
input[type='submit']{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <textarea id='EmailMsg"+i+"' name='EmailMsg' class='clsEmailMsg' rows='2' cols='50'></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' name='emailType' value='sched' id='sched' /><span class='checkboxtext'>Sched&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

            <input type='checkbox' name='emailType' value='implant' id='implant' /><span class='checkboxtext'>Implant</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <textarea id='EmailMsg"+i+"' name='EmailMsg' class='clsEmailMsg' rows='2' cols='50'></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' name='emailType' value='sched' id='sched' /><span class='checkboxtext'>Sched&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

            <input type='checkbox' name='emailType' value='implant' id='implant' /><span class='checkboxtext'>Implant</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='emailType' value='Submit' id='implant' /><span class='checkboxtext'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each keydown for every textarea check all the textareas to see if they have any data in them. If any do break out of the loop to check and show the button, otherwise hide it.

```
var $form = $('#ssdSchedDR'),
    $textareas = $form.find('textarea'),
    $submit = $form.find('input[type="submit"]');

$textareas.on('keydown', function(){
    var empty = true;

    $textareas.each(function(){
        if($(this).val() !== ''){
            empty = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!empty){
        $submit.show();
    }else{
        $submit.hide();
    }
});
```

Since looping through each textarea on every keypress can be resource intensive, you might want to look into throttling the event with something like [jQuery throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)